# PyCharm/Pyinstaller - How to optimize distribution

Tags: python, pyinstaller, directory-structure

I developed my code using PyCharm and am using PyInstaller to create a desktop `.exe` application. I am able to create the application, however, my current method requires navigating multiple directories, and to copy/paste some file dependencies. The whole reason to use PyInstaller was to make it more user-friendly, and easy to access the file dependencies. My question is, how should my code be organized so that a general user can easily access the file dependencies, and developer not need to copy/paste the dependency?

Below is my generalized current approach and the result.

To develop using PyCharm, edit:
`/projectFolder/main.py`,
`/projectFolder/helper.py`,
`/projectFolder/data.xlsx`

To create application using PyInstaller:
in command prompt, `/projectFolder/venv/Scripts`, execute `pyinstaller ../../main.py`

This creates `projectFolder/venv/Scripts/dist/main/main.exe`, among many more files (generated by PyInstaller) that the user shouldn't interact with or even see.

At this point, I need to copy/paste `/projectFolder/data.xlsx` into `/projectFolder/venv/Scripts/dist/main` for the `.exe` application to function.

The executable is now ready to be used.

I am looking for a better approach, where the user will see only the relevant files, `main.exe` and `data.xlsx` (since this will be modified, periodically). Also, I'd like `data.xlsx` need not be copy/pasted.

Again, how should I organize my code / package the distribution in order to simplify things for the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can [add files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle) or even a folder to install with PyInstaller by using the command `--add-data`. The documentation explains the format for the file / folder to add but in your case it should be:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "data.xlsx;." main.py
```

Now your 'data.xlsx' will automatically copied and pasted into the folder with your .exe file.

PyInstaller also has a feature to compress all your files into one single .exe (including added data) and then when you run your program, [it creates a temporary folder](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works) in your OS temp folder, usually `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\` that starts with `_MEIxxxxx` where the xxxx is a randomly generated number so your exe programs wont interfer with each other if more than one is running at a time. The folder is automatically deleted upon **successful** exit of the program.

The code to have only one file instead of a folder:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "data.xlsx;." main.py
```

There are 2 issues with having one file instead of a folder. The first isn't too big of a problem, but everytime your program crashes or doesn't close properly, the temp folder `_MEIxxxxx` where all your program was unloaded to wont get deleted, potentially clogging up their system. A simple fix would be to add some extra code into your program that checks if there is already a `_MEIxxxxx` folder with an older date/time in their temp folder and delete it.

The second is that if your program requires to read / write to a file, the code will check in the current directory of the exe, not the temp folder that is created. A workaround to this would be to write some extra code that looks for the a folder that starts with `_MEI` in their temp and uses that as the path. If it finds more than one folder with `_MEI` it should take the most recent (and hopefully delete the older ones)

Another cool feature is adding the `--runtime-tmpdir` command to your `pyinstaller` which allows you to specify the where you want your `_MEIxxxxx` to unload, potentially making it easier to check where the data and files you need to run the program.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --runtime-tmpdir "C:\TemporaryFolder" --add-data "data.xlsx;." main.py
```

Unfortunately, if you specify a folder or a path that doesn't exit your program wont work at all, so I would recommend creating a separate `setup.exe` that creates that folder for them and that should be run before running the `main.exe` file. Afterwards they can delete the setup file and their program should be running.